# phing+windows copy file path

Tags: windows, path, phing

How to describe in phing the task copy file? There is a problem with the paths of windows.

Is does not work:

```
<copy file = "c:\projects\somefile.txt" tofile = "c:\projects\anotherfile.bak" overwrite = "true" />
```

Error:
Execution of target "build" failed for the following reason: C:\projects\build.xml: 8: 36: Use a fileset to copy directories.

Works fine:

```
<copy file = "\projects\somefile.txt" tofile = "\projects\anotherfile.bak" overwrite = "true" />
```

or

```
<copy file = "projects\somefile.txt" tofile = "projects\anotherfile.bak" overwrite = "true" />
```

But what if you want to copy to c:\ in d:\ ?